# How do I use WP_Query for a custom post type's taxonomy using taxonomy ID?

Tags: html, wordpress, slider, taxonomy, custom-post-type

Here is the dilemma I have, my theme options passes the custom taxonomy variable as an ID number, not the slug name.  So instead of passing "news" it passses "4".

I have this hard code that works:

```
$wp_query = new WP_Query(array('slidecat' => 'extra', 'showposts'=>$slides));
```

But this code only works with the slug.  So if i replace the 'extra' with $slider_category which is the variable my select field in the theme options passes, the code doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the taxonomy ID, then it's easier to just query the database directly to get to the slug:

```
function get_term_by_taxonomy_id($term_taxonomy_id) {
    global $wpdb;
    $taxonomy = $wpdb->get_row( $wpdb->prepare( 
        "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->term_taxonomy wta
            INNER JOIN $wpdb->terms wt ON (wta.term_id = wt.term_id)
            WHERE wta.term_taxonomy_id = %d", $term_taxonomy_id 
    ) );

    return $taxonomy;
}

$cat = get_term_by_taxonomy_id($slider_category);
// at this point you should check if $cat is null (in case of an error)
$wp_query = new WP_Query(array('slidecat' => $cat->slug, 'showposts'=>$slides));
```

Of course the slug can be applied to different taxonomies, for example there could by a `category` and a `post_tag` with a slug named `"hello"`. So it depends on how `slidecat` is implemented and which taxonomies are supported.

Comment: It's not a category though, its the taxonomy for the custom post type.  that could would essentially be "get_category(4);"  How would it know I meant that custom post type's taxonomy and not a different one's or the post category?

Comment: @BRAINBUZZmedia: thank you for the comment! You are right, my solution was not correct. I have now changed my answer. It selects the taxonomy directly from the database with the taxonomy-ID and returns an object similar go `get_category` - including the `slug`.

Comment: It works! Thank you!  One question.  Is it bad to query the database?  Is that like how calling wp-load is advised against?

Comment: @BRAINBUZZmedia: Good question! I think it's bad to directly query the database if you have at least one function/class which does what you want. I always search the reference doc and the source (grepping for the table/field names) before making a direct query. If I absolutely have to use a query, then I make sure that it follows the best practices to prevent SQL-injections.